# Jython jInternalFrame Listener

Tags: listener, jython, jinternalframe

I was able to get a listener working for a JFrame, but I'm missing something with doing the same thing with a JInternalFrame. I built up some basic code from various samples I found, and I'm hoping someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong in creating the internal frame listener. I made the code as simple as possible, and all I want to do change the size of the internal frame and button when I click on NewIframe>Open.

edit: I think I got it working, but didn't want to leave this hanging. I thought I had to use the InternalFrameAdapter, but I used the ComponentAdapter instead. Now, componentResized is called whenever I change the size of the internal frame I created.

```
from javax.swing import JButton, JFrame, JPanel,JMenuBar,JMenu,JMenuItem,JInternalFrame,JDesktopPane,JScrollPane
from java.awt.event import ComponentListener,ComponentAdapter
from javax.swing.event import InternalFrameListener,InternalFrameAdapter

class TestApp(JFrame):
    def __init__(self):
        JFrame.__init__(self,'Main Window',size=(500, 500),defaultCloseOperation=JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)
        self.createDesktop()
        self.createMenus()

    def createDesktop(self):
        self.desktop = JDesktopPane()
        self.contentPane.add(JScrollPane(self.desktop)) # This is the same as self.getContentPane().add(...)

    def createMenus(self):
        bar = JMenuBar()
        self.setJMenuBar(bar)     
        f = JMenu("New IFrame")
        newfile = JMenuItem("Open",actionPerformed = self.createInternalFrame)
        f.add(newfile)
        bar.add(f)
 
    def createInternalFrame(self, event):
        iframe     = JInternalFrame('InternalFrame', 1, 1, 1, 1, size=(400, 400), visible=1)
        iframe.setLayout(None)
        c= JPanel()
        c.setBounds(10,10,60,60)
        a = JButton("Report",actionPerformed=self.onClick)
        c.add(a)
        iframe.add(c)
        iframe.addComponentListener(listen(iframe))
        self.desktop.add(iframe)
    def onClick(self,widget):
        print 'Report'
        
class listen(ComponentAdapter):
    def __init__( self, app ):
        print 'listen'
        self.app = app
    def componentResized( self, ce):
        print "Hey, I'm listening!"
        #--Change frame size to (450,450)
        #--set button bounds to (20,20,70,70)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = TestApp()
    a.setLocation(100, 100)
    a.show()
```

Ignore that I'm not using a layout manager and that I don't check that the frame is already open- I'll fix that later. I just want to get the listener working. Thank you!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what platform are you using to code this?

Comment: I am using Windows 10

Comment: Oops. I meant IDE

Comment: I used Eclipse.